# Have cruciferous vegetables been genetically altered to reduce cooking odors?

Tags: plant-physiology

As a young girl my mother always kept a bottle of "Air Wick" under the kitchen sink. When she cooked cabbage, cauliflower, broccoli, etc., she would open the bottle, pull out a green sponge that was on a wire, and place the opened bottle on the counter. It absorbed the strong odors of those foods that would normally penetrate other rooms. Today when I cook those same vegetables I don't notice those strong odors of my youth. Have those vegetables been genetically altered to reduce their strong, lingering odors?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, it is important to define what you mean by "genetically altered" — almost every food we eat has been under selection by humans for many generations. Is that what you are trying to ask about? ——— We also encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks! 

Comment: perhaps she cooked it for longer and used difference of oil/salt/vinegar.

Comment: Perhaps your sense of smell is not as good as it was when you were young?  I'd also be more than a little skeptical about the "absorbing odors" claim.